# AWS S3 bucket default storage class

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I've been trying to change default storage class in one of my buckets to glacier for one user using IAM policy but unfortunately it does not work. Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong? Every uploaded file still use Standard storage class.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::$MY_ACCOUNT_ID:user/backup"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::private-backup/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-storage-class": "GLACIER"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does the `backup` user have any other policies which would allow writing to S3? maybe bucket policy allows this?

Comment: Yes, backup user has policy allows put, get, delete objects. I've also tested this same policy on admin user and result was the same.

Comment: By the way, I noticed that you have a number of questions, with answers. Yet not a single answer was ever accepted. Accepting hepfull answers is a good practice, helps other users and reduces number of duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

If your users or bucket has other policies that allow such uploads, you have to use **explicit deny** in your policy, not allow:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "statement1",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::$MY_ACCOUNT_ID:user/backup"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::private-backup/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-storage-class": "GLACIER"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Trying with deny i lost access to put object to the bucket and it's quite obvious for me.

Comment: @adamo89 It will only work for putting directly to glacier.

Comment: What is the difference? Both are object from S3 perspective.

Comment: @adamo89 Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. This is what you wanted to obtain in your question - uploads only to glacier.

Comment: Exactly, every object that is uploaded to this bucket by user backup to be stored on glacier without lifecycle rules.

Comment: @adamo89 Yes. So I'm not sure what is the problem. When backup uploads object he/she needs to specify glacier class explicitly.

Comment: But this step needs to be done manually i want to change the default storage class for this bucket according to the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html#example-storage-class-condition-key

Comment: @adamo89 If you don't want to use lifestyles, this is the only way.

Comment: Yes i know but it doesn’t work, that’s the reason i added question here.